# uploading a php script on a server on executing it on server getting a 200 as response code but not the desired respose

Tags: php, rest-client

I am uploading a `php script` on a server using ftp.
after that I am Using ruby `Restclient` to invoke that php script.
in response I am getting a html doc, not the desired response, but response code is 200.
after retrying it, I get proper response
what can causing this kind of behavior?
please give suggestions so that I can handle these problems in future with proper error message.

Comment: what append when you access the script with your browser ?

Comment: Most probably there is a syntax error in your script. You can see the description in the error.log. Post it here.

Comment: no error is coming, its sending html data. and this problem is not persistent it comes some times not always.